# Rails/ActiveRecord Order Issue with string vs symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having an issue applying a dynamic order method on a Rails Active Record query.  The order by field and direction are dynamic based on the request params.  When specifying them as a string, it gets tripped up on ambiguous field names.  When specifying as a symbol, it's fine.  How can I dynamically make this query with a symbol?

This:

```
subject = subject.order('id desc')
```

Results In `SELECT  DISTINCT "projects"."id", id AS alias_0 FROM...` and gives a `PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous` error.

When specifying this using symbols, Active Record correctly puts it all together without the ambiguity:

```
subject = subject.order(id: :asc)
```

So how can I convert or use this method dynamically, such as:

```
subject = subject.order(params[:order_by] + ' ' + params[:order_direction])
```

Side note: There are joins and other complexity happening elsewhere in the query which I'm assuming is contributing to the issue (multiple `id` fields), but again as symbols Active Record figures it all out properly.  Also, the `order_by` and `order_direction` in the params example above are being whitelisted, so SQL injection is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a hash with symbolized keys like this:

```
order = {}
order[params[:order_by].to_sym] = params[:order_direction]
subject = subject.order(order)
```

Not sure that this will prevent the AmbiguousColumn error, though

Answer (score 0):

> Short answer

```
subject = subject.order(params[:order_by].to_sym => params[:order_direction].to_sym)
```